# Could not see value changes in HTML in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this on my component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DrinkType } from 'src/app/_models/drinkType.model';
import { DrinkTypeService } from 'src/app/_services/drink-type.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-sale',
  templateUrl: './add-sale.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-sale.component.scss']
})
export class AddSaleComponent implements OnInit {

  drinkTypeList: any[];
  drinkTypes: DrinkType[];

  selectedDrink: DrinkType;

  drinkQuantity = 0;

  constructor(
    private dts: DrinkTypeService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getDrinkTypes();
    this.drinkQuantity = 0;
  }

  getDrinkTypes() {
    this.dts.getDrinkTypes().subscribe(res => {
      this.drinkTypeList = res.map(item => {
        return {
          id: item.payload.doc.id,
          ...item.payload.doc.data()
        }
      });
      this.drinkTypes = this.drinkTypeList;
    });
  }

  onSelectDrink(drinkType: DrinkType) {
    this.drinkQuantity = 0;
    this.selectedDrink = drinkType;
  }

  onAddQuantity() {
    this.drinkQuantity = this.drinkQuantity + 1;
    console.log(this.drinkQuantity);
  }

  onReduceQuantity() {
    this.drinkQuantity = this.drinkQuantity - 1;
    console.log(this.drinkQuantity);
  }
}
```

and in my html

```
<div mdbModal #drinkQuantity="mdb-modal" class="modal fade bottom" id="centralModalSuccess" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-notify modal-success" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <p class="heading lead"><mdb-icon fas icon="glass-martini-alt"></mdb-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; {{ selectedDrink?.name }}</p>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="drinkQuantity.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true" class="white-text">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="text-center">
          <span>
            <mdb-icon fas icon="plus" (click)="onAddQuantity()" size="4x" class="mb-3 animated rotateIn"></mdb-icon>
          </span>
           <h1>
             {{drinkQuantity | json}}
           </h1>
            <mdb-icon fas icon="minus" (click)="onReduceQuantity()" size="4x" class="mb-3 animated rotateIn"></mdb-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-primary-modal waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Get it now
          <mdb-icon far icon="gem" class=" ml-1"></mdb-icon>
        </a>
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary-modal" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="drinkQuantity.hide()" mdbWavesEffect>No, thanks</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use the {{drinkQuantity | json }} I get this error:

> ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Subscriber'
> |     property '_subscriptions' -> object with constructor 'Array'
> |     index 0 -> object with constructor 'SubjectSubscription'
> --- property '_parentOrParents' closes the circle

This div is in my modal of the same component. What I can't figure out is why is it when I show this modal, the {{drinkQuantity}} is [object object] and when I click on the icons, I get the result in the console but not on the HTML.

Comment: Can you post more code of your ts and html? Because by looking this, everything looks good

Comment: Can you share it in stackbiltz

Comment: The `span` tag is not spelled correctly. Can you try `{{drinkQuantity | json}}` to check what is the value for `drinkQuantity`

Comment: Try again after correcting <spam> tag into <span>

Comment: Please see my edit... Thank you.

Comment: try drinkQuantity: number;  in class and set this.drinkQuantity = 0 in ngOnInit

Comment: @hackerbuddy I did as you suggested.I still get the same issue...

Comment: But if I make the drinkQuantity to string, I can actually see the string in the html.

Comment: I got it.. drinkQuantity is in the name of the modal so that is what the html is trying to show.